# DurableTask not registered after zip deploy from VSTS to Azure Functions v2

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-durable-functions

I have functions app with durable functions written with C# Scripts that runs locally fine.

I created VSTS build with tasks: NuGet Restore, dotnet build/publish, Archive Files zip, Publish Artifact: drop.

After deploying to Azure App Service (Azure Functions v2) I'm getting an error:

> The binding type(s) 'orchestrationClient' are not registered. Please ensure the type is correct and the binding extension is installed.

Deploying from VS Code Azure Functions Extension also works fine.

How can I properly install binding extension with VSTS?

Answer (score 2):

When using zipdeploy, you need to make sure that the zip file contains all the artifacts that are needed to run, this is particularly important when running [from a zip package](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/84), where wwwroot becomes read-only.

So the suggestion here is: look at the content of wwwroot using Kudu Console, figure out what's missing, and fix your build task to have it all included in your zip.

Comment: I tried to do all build steps locally and found that "dotnet build" step doesn't install func extensions properly. I get same error. But after running "func extensions install" command app starts fine. How can I run/recreate "func extensions install" command in VSTS?

Comment: @deman4ik it should just be a nuget restore on the csproj, and VSTS has a task for that.